# Django CharField, choices and migration

Tags: django

For some reason Django asks me to migrate randomly, when this field isn't changed. The migration files are the same.

Model:

```
PROGRESS_CHOICE = {
        ('1', '1.start'),
        ('2', '2.driver_arrived_pick_up'),
        ('3', '3.hope_in'),
        ('4', '4.driver_arrived_destination'),
        ('5', '5.end')
    }

    progress = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=PROGRESS_CHOICE, default=1, blank=True)
```

Migrations: 1.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('api', '0031_auto_20150603_1515'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='ride',
            name='progress',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=20, default=1, blank=True, choices=[('1', '1.start'), ('3', '3.hope_in'), ('4', '4.driver_arrived_destination'), ('2', '2.driver_arrived_pick_up'), ('5', '5.end')]),
            preserve_default=True,
        ),
    ]
```

2.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('api', '0032_auto_20150603_1734'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='ride',
            name='progress',
            field=models.CharField(default=1, max_length=20, choices=[('1', '1.start'), ('4', '4.driver_arrived_destination'), ('5', '5.end'), ('3', '3.hope_in'), ('2', '2.driver_arrived_pick_up')], blank=True),
            preserve_default=True,
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It happened because `PROGRESS_CHOICE` is a `dict` while it must be a `list` or better a `tuple`.

```
PROGRESS_CHOICES = (
    ('1', '1.start'),
    ('2', '2.driver_arrived_pick_up'),
    ('3', '3.hope_in'),
    ('4', '4.driver_arrived_destination'),
    ('5', '5.end'),
)
```

CharField's `choices` accept any iterable so it worked but `dict` does not preserve order so every time you make migrations it is randomly shuffled while being transformed to list.

Answer (score 1):

Your default type doesn't match with your choices. Try to change to default='1'.